# how to sort Data Sources in terraform based on arguments

Tags: sorting, terraform, alibaba-cloud

I use following terraform code to get a list of available db resources:

```
data "alicloud_db_instance_classes" "resources" {
  instance_charge_type = "PostPaid"
  engine               = "PostgreSQL"
  engine_version       = "10.0"
  category = "HighAvailability"
  zone_id = "${data.alicloud_zones.rds_zones.ids.0}"
  multi_zone = true
  output_file = "./classes.txt"
}
```

And the output file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "instance_class": "pg.x4.large.2",
        "storage_range": {
            "max": "500",
            "min": "250",
            "step": "250"
        },
        "zone_ids": [
            {
                "id": "cn-shanghai-MAZ1(b,c)",
                "sub_zone_ids": [
                    "cn-shanghai-b",
                    "cn-shanghai-c"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instance_class": "pg.x8.medium.2",
        "storage_range": {
            "max": "250",
            "min": "250",
            "step": "0"
        },
        "zone_ids": [
            {
                "id": "cn-shanghai-MAZ1(b,c)",
                "sub_zone_ids": [
                    "cn-shanghai-b",
                    "cn-shanghai-c"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instance_class": "rds.pg.c1.xlarge",
        "storage_range": {
            "max": "2000",
            "min": "5",
            "step": "5"
        },
        "zone_ids": [
            {
                "id": "cn-shanghai-MAZ1(b,c)",
                "sub_zone_ids": [
                    "cn-shanghai-b",
                    "cn-shanghai-c"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instance_class": "rds.pg.s1.small",
        "storage_range": {
            "max": "2000",
            "min": "5",
            "step": "5"
        },
        "zone_ids": [
            {
                "id": "cn-shanghai-MAZ1(b,c)",
                "sub_zone_ids": [
                    "cn-shanghai-b",
                    "cn-shanghai-c"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I want to get the one that's cheapest.

One way to do so is by sorting with storage-range.min， but how do I sort this list based on 'storage_range.min'?

Or I can filter by 'instance_class', but "alicloud_db_instance_classes" doesn't seem to like filter as it says: Error: data.alicloud_db_instance_classes.resources: : invalid or unknown key: filter

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `sort()` function orders lexicographical and you have no simple key here.
You can use filtering with some code like this (v0.12)

```
locals {
  best_db_instance_class_key = "rds.pg.s1.small"
  best_db_instance_class = element( alicloud_db_instance_classes.resources, index(alicloud_db_instance_classes.resources.*.instance_class, best_db_instance_class_key) )
}
```

(Untested code)